# Get Chrome to not identify itself?

Tags: google-chrome, user-agent

Is there any way that I can get chrome to identify itself as a different (or unspecified) browswer?

Comment: What you're looking for is a *"user agent" switcher*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a shortcut to Chrome and edit the path:

...somerandompath/chrome.exe --user-agent="User Agent String"

Thanks to http://knol.google.com/k/wardog-l/google-chrome-change-user-agent-to/187t5jnwvnu9d/6#

Some suggestions show how to modify the Chrome dll to further hard set the User Agent String. But this method allows you to keep a single unmodified install supporting multiple possible user agent strings.

Answer (score 4):

This Chrome extension allows you to change navigator.userAgent and navigator.vendor in-browser: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aafciojnlamllgpkpdkbamkfgbofhgcj

It won't let you change the user agent headers, however.